# How do I derive specific data from a string using the Java standard API?

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, arrays

I have the following pattern:

```
Jan(COMPANY) &^% Feb(ASP) 567 Mar(INC)
```

I want the final output to be:

```
String[] one = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar"};
String[] two = {"COMPANY","ASP","INC"};
```

Please help. Anyone!!?

Comment: A good, well-formed question, is one in which the requirements are spelled out ahead of time, and do not change.  Your requirements are unclear, and they have changed as per your comments below. -1

Comment: I have to agree with this. Considering it's his first question, it's understandable though. @OP: I bet your next question is crystal clear ;)

Comment: oh sorry about tat! My mind works in agile mode :P

Comment: @aioobe: i post another question. can u please have a look at it

Comment: I answered your other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complete example that stores the results in `String[] one` and `String[] two` would look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Jan(COMPANY) &^% Feb(ASP) 567 Mar(INC)";

        ArrayList<String> monthArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> dataArr  = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Part 1: \\b(\\p{Alpha}+): Word boundary, one or more characters
        // Part 2: \\(([^)]+)\\): "(", anything but ")" one or more times, ")" 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\p{Alpha}+)\\(([^)]+)\\)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        while (m.find()) {
            monthArr.add(m.group(1));  // m.group(1) = "Jan", "Feb" and so on
            dataArr.add(m.group(2));   // m.group(2) = "COMPANY, "ASP", and so on
        }

        String[] one = monthArr.toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] two = dataArr.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not use the Java String API, as requested by the OP.

Comment: I'd say that Javas regular expression API is a part of the API for strings. Depends on how you interpret the question though. (btw, is ArrayList part of the string api? ;)

Comment: Nope, but I used the String API in my answer.  I do not consider the `java.util.regex` package as part of the Java String API.  If the subject had been "To derive specific data from a string using regex", I would be on board with your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Can u temme how this works..."([A-Z][a-z]{2})\\\(([^)]+)\\\)"

Comment: Oh, it's just a capital letter `[A-Z]`, followed by 2 `{2}` lower case letters. You could also have for instance `[A-Za-z]{3}` if you like three arbitrarily cased letters. Or, if it's only months, you could do `Jan|Feb|Mar|...|Dec`.

Comment: And what if i'm not sure of the number of letters?

Comment: Then I'd use `p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\p{Alpha}+)\\(([^)]+)\\)")` which says, "word-boundary", "one or more alphabetical characters", followed by "(" ...  Updated the answer.

Comment: If you want to include digits, change alpha, to alnum: `p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\p{Alnum}+)\(([^)]+)\)")`

Comment: Then you should accept the answer by clicking the checkbox ;)

Comment: if str = "Jan(COMPANY) &^% (Feb(ASP)) 567 Mar(INC)"; the format of the o/p has to be same even with the extra paranthesis...(Feb(ASP))

Comment: sure. But I recommend you to ask a new question. This "comment" thread has sort of out-grown the question.

Comment: suppose the string contains a term like rain-drop. only drop is logged.

Comment: I removed my DV from your answer, and replaced it with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate across the characters in the string and store what you need.

```
String s = "Jan(COMPANY) &^% Feb(ASP) 567 Mar(INC)";

ArrayList<String> monthsList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> companyList = new ArrayList<String>();

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);

    switch (c) {

    case ' ':
        b.setLength(0);
        break;
    case '(':
        monthsList.add(b.toString());
        b.setLength(0);
        break;
    case ')':
        companyList.add(b.toString());
        b.setLength(0);
        break;
    default:
        b.append(c);
        break;
    }
}

String[] monthArray = monthsList.toArray(new String[] {});
String[] companyArray = companyList.toArray(new String[] {});
```